# Android Rotation with IntentService

Tags: android, rotation, intentservice

I have an application that uses IntentService to run a background task where I pull data from a website, parse the data out, and create calendar events based on the results.  Everything seems to be working create, except I'm running into an issue with rotation.
Using the code below, when I rotate the screen, the ProgressDialog box stays visible, but is never updated with new text when the process is updated, and never goes away once the call is completed.  I'm using an IntentService instead of an ASyncTask because the user can also schedule the IntentService to run at other times without having to interface with the app.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Object retained = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (retained instanceof CalendarHandler) {
        // CH is a class level variable defined at the top which references my IntentService, aptly named CalendarHandler
        ch = (CalendarHandler) retained;
        ch.setActivity(this);
    } else {
        ch = null;
    }
    activity = this;

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener(View view) {
            ch = new CalendarHandler();
            ch.setActivity(MyTlc.this);
            // Do other stuff, like run the intent service
    }
}

public Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        // We read the information from the message and do something with it
        // based on what the result code is
        String result = message.getData().getString("status");
        if (result.equals("ERROR")) {
            activity.removeDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
            results.setText(message.getData().getString("error"));
        } else if (result.equals("DONE")) {
            activity.removeDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
            int count = message.getData().getInt("count", 0);
            activity.results.setText("Added " + count + " shifts to the calendar");
        } else {
            activity.pDialog.setMessage(result);
        }
        super.handleMessage(message);
    }
};
```

From what I understand, this should work, and like I said the ProgressDialog box does stay properly, I just can't seem to pass information to the dialog box after rotating.